# Axios not fetching EJS files properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, axios

I'm trying to get the HTML string of two EJS files I have in my project, one is 'index.ejs' and the other is 'page2.ejs'.

I'm rendering these two in my server.js file and they are all working fine.

But the problem is when I want to fetch them to get their HTML using axios, it returns weird data.

My server code to fetch 'index.ejs' to get the HTML:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const axios = require('axios');

app.listen(5500)
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
});

app.get('/page2', (req, res) => {
    res.render('page2');
});

axios('http://localhost:5500')
    .then(response => console.log(response.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

The response I get back:

```
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[
  'node_modules',
  'package-lock.json',
  'package.json',
  'public',
  'server.js',
  'views'
]
```

And when I try to fetch 'page2.ejs' to get the HTML:

```
axios('http://localhost:5500/page2')
    .then(response => console.log(response.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

The response I get back:

```
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Folders\Programming\Web Development\Web-Development-Projects\Test\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)  
    at settle (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Folders\Programming\Web Development\Web-Development-Projects\Test\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Folders\Programming\Web Development\Web-Development-Projects\Test\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:312:11)
```

Why am I getting wrong data on the first? and an error on the second?

Comment: Why would you run an axios request to your server from the same server? This is almost certainly an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/) so please tell us why you're doing this in the first place.

Comment: In case it's not clear: server routes are usually requested from the client-side. You don't even have express set up to serve static files though.

Comment: @ChrisG Hey Chris, I'm just trying to see what would happen if you request an EJS file from the server side.  

Because I want to try web scraping websites, and I want to see will I be able to get the data if that website is running a template engine like EJS?

Because I already know you can scrape HTML templates and extract data you want, but not sure about EJS.

Comment: @ChrisG So for example, if a website is running regular HTML, you easily run axios/cheerio and extract the data you want, but what if that website was running EJS instead? will you be able to extract the data?

Comment: Using ejs just means that instead of serving static HTML you're serving dynamic HTML. The end result is the same though: HTML. The program that does the scraping, only gets to see the end result, and it has no idea how the HTML (or whatever else the server might send back) was composed. A scraper that requests routes from your server will not see the ejs file itself, it will see the output of res.render(), which is just HTML. The parsing of the ejs template and the insertion of data, looping and whatever else templates support, all happens on the server, invisible to the scraper.

Comment: If you want to see what a scraper sees, just open the URL in a browser and press CTRL+U.